# How to create a super simple AngularJS directive for using GSAP TweenMax?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, gsap

I'd like to use a TweenMax animation in my AngularJS project, and instead of justwriting the code in a controller, i'd like to do it the correct way, and use it via a directive.

Here's my element:

```
<ul>
  <li class="foo">A</li>
  <li class="foo">B</li>
  <li class="foo">C</li>
</ul>
```

Here's my animation:

```
var ease = Elastic.easeOut;

TweenMax.staggerFrom(".foo", 1.5, {
  scale: 0.7,
  opacity: 0,
  delay: 0.5,
  ease: ease
}, 0.1);
```

How do I do wrap it in a directive?

Comment: do you wanted to render them using `ng-repeat`?

Comment: No, i'd prefer to have the directive on the parent (the <ul>), because the children can't really be made dynamic with an ng-repeat in my project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have directive on wrapper element like below, that would have `element.children()` which will apply that effect over each DOM by queuing them up.

**Markup**

```
<ul tween-max-stragger>
    <li class="foo">A</li>
    <li class="foo">B</li>
    <li class="foo">C</li>
</ul>
```

**Directive**

```
.directive('tweenMaxStragger', function() {
    return function(scope, element, attrs) {
      var ease = Elastic.easeOut;
      TweenMax.staggerFrom(element.children(), 1.5, {
        scale: 0.7,
        opacity: 0,
        delay: 0.5,
        ease: ease
      }, 0.1);
    }
})
```

[**Codepen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jqNKgB?editors=1010)

Comment: `element.find('li.foo')`

Comment: Thank you @PankajParkar! This is great. 
And if I wanna wanna make the "element.find('li')" part dynamic, so i can use this on other elements too, how do I do that?

Comment: @Kriszta look at updated.. you could use `element.children()` to have inner element dynamically

Comment: Glad to know that.. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

If you're not using `ng-repeat` in the list, you can do something like this.

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .directive('fancyList', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'C',
      link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
        TweenMax.staggerFrom(elem.find('li'), 1.5, {
          scale: 0.7,
          opacity: 0,
          delay: 0.5,
          ease: Elastic.easeOut
        }, 0.1);
      }
    };
  })
```

And then write your html like this:

```
<ul class="fancy-list">
  <li>A</li>
  <li>B</li>
</ul>
```

You can't really write a directive on each of your `<li>` elems because they're all dependent on the previous animation. The next best thing to do is write a directive for the parent element that wraps all staggered animations.